# Incorrect timeout using HZ value

Tags: linux-kernel, timeout, linux-device-driver

Running the function with timeout parameter, I found that hard-coded 10000 value gives 10 seconds timeout, and `10*HZ` value gives 2.5 seconds timeout:

```
usb_bulk_msg(context->udev, pipe, context->buffer, context_size, &bytes_read,
    10000 );    // 10 seconds
//  10*HZ);     // 2.5 seconds
```

HZ value printed with printk gives 250 - this value is incorrect. Looking in the Linux source: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/asm-generic/param.h#L6, I see that `HZ` is defined as `CONFIG_HZ` - looks like configuration parameter. Why this value is incorrect, is there another way to specify jiffies timeout?

Ubuntu 12.04, 32 bit, kernel version 3.2.34.

Comment: `usb_bulk_msg` takes a number of milliseconds *by design*, not a number of jiffies.

Comment: @Tinctorius: Thanks. Please post this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because [`usb_bulk_msg`](http://docs.blackfin.uclinux.org/kernel/generated/usb/re61.html) takes the number milliseconds, not the number of jiffies, as its sixth argument:

> *timeout*
>
> > time in msecs to wait for the message to complete before timing out (if 0 the wait is forever)